# Unable to exec() a PHP script from running PHP site in HHVM

Tags: php, hhvm

I'm running a PHP site that runs using HHVM/NGINX

```
/usr/bin/hhvm --config /etc/hhvm/php.ini \ 
              --config /etc/hhvm/server.ini \
              --user www-data \
              --mode daemon
```

I tried executing another PHP file using `exec` through the PHP file served by the HHVM server. Something like below.

```
echo exec('another_file.php');
```

But it won't output anything. But the line below

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

works. It returned `www-data`.

So I tried SSH to the server and did this.

```
sudo -u www-data bash
php another_file.php
```

This returned

```
Failed to initialize central HHBC repository:
   Failed to initialize schema in /home/ubuntu/.hhvm.hhbc: 
   Failed to open /var/www/.hhvm.hhbc: 14 - unable to open database file
```

How do I enable this?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem. Make sure the `/var/www` and `/home/ubuntu` directories have write permissions for the `www-data` user. Also your exec() command would need to be `exec('php another_file.php');`

Comment: The `another_file.php` already have `#!/usr/bin/env php`. Your idea seems to make sense. Let me try first.

Comment: @Jeemusu turns out creating file `/var/www/.hhvm.hhbc` using `www-data` permission solves the problem. Thanks!